# How to call another setInterval once one has been completed and then reset to the default time for a Pomodoro Project

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend

I am trying to figure out how to call my "breakValue" once the "defaultClockTime" is "0:00", this is after the start.onclick has been called and the "studyValue" has been completed. I want my studyIterations to increase once the "studyValue" is completed and then once the "breakValue" has also been completed for this to increase also. Once that is done I want it to then redefault back to the original time.

please see [codepen](https://codepen.io/Buxey/pen/RwrRNoQ)

I have tried multiple IF statements to try and create some kind of rule that once that is met to call the breakValue function but the way in which I have it so far is that the code will just keep looping around as the condition of "if (time == -1)" will keep being met and will not break out of that loop? and I cannot figure out a way to resolve my problem

I have looked at multiple pomodoro projects on this site and other's on codepen but their code is not giving me the answer I need as mine is written with vanilla JS and theirs is usually using Jquery or some kind of front end framework.

please can someone help me with this last piece of my project I have spent days trying to figure this out in vanilla JS.

any questions please ask!

```
<body>
   <div id="pomodoroContainer">
      <h1 id="heading">Pomodoro Clock</h1>
      <div class="timerContainer">
         <h2 id="time"><time>25:00</time></h2>
         <img id="start" src="./src/img/play-button.svg" height="30px">
         <img id="reset" src="./src/img/restart.svg" height="30px">
      </div>
      <div>
         <img id="StudyTomato" src="./src/img/tomato.png">
         <span id="studyIterations">0</span>
         <img id="breakCoffee" src="./src/img/study.png">
         <span id="breakIterations">0</span>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="breakAndTimeContainer">
      <div id="studyTime">
         <h3 id="studyValue"><time>25</time></h3>
         <p>Study Time</p>
         <button id="decreaseStudyValue">-</button>
         <button id="increaseStudyValue">+</button>
      </div>
      <div id="breakTime">
         <h3 id="breakValue"><time>5</time></h3>
         <p>Break Time</p>
         <button id="decreaseBreakValue">-</button>
         <button id="increaseBreakValue">+</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
<script src="./src/app.js"></script>



    clock = document.getElementById('time');
    start = document.getElementById('start');
    reset = document.getElementById('reset');

    studyIterations = document.getElementById('studyIterations');
    breakIterations = document.getElementById('breakIterations');

    studyValue = document.getElementById('studyValue');
    decreaseStudyValue = document.getElementById('decreaseStudyValue');
    increaseStudyValue = document.getElementById('increaseStudyValue');


    breakValue = document.getElementById('breakValue');
    decreaseBreakValue = document.getElementById('decreaseBreakValue');
    increaseBreakValue = document.getElementById('increaseBreakValue');

    let defaultClockTime = 25;
    let time = defaultClockTime * 60;
    let studyIterationsValue = 0;
    let breakIterationsValue = 0;
    let defaultStudyTime = 25;
    let defaultBreakTime = 5;
    let intervalId;

    clockCountdown = () => {
        const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60);
        let seconds = time % 60;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? '0' + seconds : seconds;
        clock.innerHTML = `${minutes}:${seconds}`;
        time--;

        if (time == -1) {
            studyIterationsValue++;
            studyIterations.innerHTML = studyIterationsValue;
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
        if (time == -1) {
            time = defaultBreakTime * 60;
            breakIterationsValue++;
            breakIterations.innerHTML = breakIterationsValue;
            clearInterval(intervalId);
        }
    }

    start.onclick = function () {
        intervalId = setInterval(clockCountdown, 1000);
        time = defaultClockTime * 60;
    }

    reset.onclick = function () {
        clearInterval(intervalId);
        clock.innerHTML = defaultClockTime + ':00'
        time = defaultClockTime * 60;
    }

    breakValue = () => {
        intervalId = setInterval(clockCountdown, 1000);
        time = defaultBreakTime * 60;
    }

    increaseStudyValue.onclick = function () {
        defaultStudyTime++;
        studyValue.innerHTML = defaultStudyTime;
        defaultClockTime++
        time = defaultClockTime * 60;
        clock.innerHTML = defaultClockTime + ':00'

    }

    decreaseStudyValue.onclick = function () {
        defaultStudyTime--;
        studyValue.innerHTML = defaultStudyTime;
        defaultClockTime--;
        time = defaultClockTime * 60;
        clock.innerHTML = defaultClockTime + ':00'
    }

    increaseBreakValue.onclick = function () {
        defaultBreakTime++;
        breakValue.innerHTML = defaultBreakTime;
        time = defaultBreakTime * 60;
    }

    decreaseBreakValue.onclick = function () {
        defaultBreakTime--;
        breakValue.innerHTML = defaultBreakTime;
        time = defaultBreakTime * 60;
    }
```

Comment: If you don't mind, please consider using "use strict" in code - I got as far as "`ReferenceError: assignment to undeclared variable clock`" before giving up. Putting `alt` tags on images, or _changing them to buttons_ before posting would also help with answering.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply, how do I use "use strict"? Sorry I'm a new Developer?

Comment: You can lookup the answer by bookmarking [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and searching the site for `"use strict"`. Short answer here is that to get better error messages, make `"use strict;"` the first [expression] statement in your code.